# vCenter SSO + vSphere questions

Tags: vmware-vsphere, vmware-vcenter

1, When installing the SSO service it doesn't pick up AD as a valid identity source, but according to the documentation, it should. I'm running the installation as a local administrator, and the box is joined into the AD domain, however, I don't have domain admin privileges. Should I try it while logged in with a user from the domain, or does it really have to be a domain admin user logged in to install the SSO service?

2, The documentation explicitly sais that if I use OpenLDAP and there's a special character in the login name, like a "@", it won't work. However, in our organization, all of the users have IDs like that. Is there a way to get it to work, even unofficially?

3, currently on the hypervisor I'm using AD authentication; if I migrate such a system to a vcenter which does not have AD in the SSO identity sources, will the users still be able to log in on the hypervisor itself using their AD credentials? (if I don't disable local logins on the vSphere nodes, of course).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to install SSO as a domain user to make auto-discovery work.
This user needs admin privileges on the vCenter server, but does NOT need to be a domain admin.

I'm not sure about your OpenLDAP question. You want to use AD authentication, right?

According to your third question - if the hosts are joined to the domain you will still be able to log in directly to them using AD accounts, no matter what you have configured for SSO, since the hosts do not use SSO for authentication.

Comment: actually we do have AD AND LDAP together, with different users; it would be nice to allow the LDAP users to log in too. Thanks for the answer, tho, I'll give it a try and report back!

Answer (score 0):

You need to install as a domain-joined user. I typically have Administrative rights in the domain in which I'm installing vSphere, so I don't know that things would would as a non-privileged user.

I don't understand your LDAP question. Aren't you using Active Directory?